# Show Hidden Sub-Menu OnClick By Avoiding Link Of Parent Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am working on a project where the most bad thing is that I can't edit HTML code of my project. I can only edit CSS/JavaScript. My project is that I have a list of menu using `<ul><li>...` having sub-list also in it. The full HTML code is giving below...

```
<ul class="main_list">
 <li class="parent">
  <a href="##########">Menu-1</a>
   <ul class="children">
    <li><a href="##########">SubMenu-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="##########">SubMenu-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="##########">SubMenu-3</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="##########">Menu-2</a></li>
 <li><a href="##########">Menu-3</a></li>
 <li><a href="##########">Menu-4</a></li>
 <li class="parent">
  <a href="##########">Menu-5</a>
   <ul class="children">
    <li><a href="##########">SubMenu-1</a></li>
    <li><a href="##########">SubMenu-2</a></li>
    <li><a href="##########">SubMenu-3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is the HTML code that I can not edit. I can only edit or add CSS/JavaScript. Here I want to hide all `children` menus and will show on click of there parent menu. But when we click on there parent menu then it goes to the external link that is on parent menu. So is there any way or solution for this...???

**Update:**
Keep in mind that I also want the parent menu link working too. I have an idea to add some text in front to parent menu like `show/hide` and make some JavaScript to open its children menu and in this case parent menu link will also work if we will click on it directly. Now can we add some text/icon in front of parent menu using JavaScript as I can't edit HTML?

Comment: Let the children menus come out on `:hover`? If that's not a possible solution, please create a JSFiddle so we can play around with it.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` in your click-function

Comment: @Rvervuurt Yes, I can handle it with `:hover` but I want to leave it open after click.

Comment: @empiric I also want the parent menu link working too... :(

Comment: Opening the menu and keeping the parent link working seem to be contradictory objectives. If clicking the menu item opens the submenu then the parent link shouldnt work (otherwise the browser would navigate away from the page before the user can interact with the submenu). You could append some kind of drop down arrow next to the menu item for items with children - clicks on the parent item would navigate to it's link but clicks on the arrow would open up the submenu.

Comment: @JRulle Yes this is the problem and I also updated this problem in question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click-function:

```
$('.main_list .parent > a').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var href = $(this).attr('href'); // save the href for further use
    $(this).siblings('.children').show(); //or whatever show-function you want to use

   window.location.href = href; //if you want to user to be redirected
   //OR
   window.open(href,'_blank'); //for opening a new tab

});
```

For your second request, you can do somethin like that:

```
$(document).ready(function{
    $('.main_list .parent').prepend('<span class="show">Show</span>');
});
```

then your selector in the click-handler above would be:

`$('.show')`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wh3mfjwk/1/)**

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I added i fiddle in my answer

Comment: yes you can add multiple classes via `.addClass()`[ref](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) to the element.

Comment: for adding the text after the link you could use `.append()` instead of `.prepend()`

Answer (score 1):

Cach your parent click event via JavaScript, then use event.preventDefault() to stop redirecting, then u can make some logic to show/hide menu items.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.each('.parent', function(){
          $(this).prepend('<div class="clickableBox"></div>');
    })

    $(document).on('click', '.clickableBox', function(event){       
       //show/hide logic here
    })
})
```

Comment: In this case u should add a div box before or after your .parent class elements , and perform your show/hide elements just when user click on that added box. so i will update my answer now

Comment: the `$.each` isn't necessary here, as described in the [api](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) `[...]to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements`

Comment: yes you can obtain your functionality without each function to. here is the fiddle  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/d7xwcvvj/27/)

Comment: @eXpas Yes. Your FIDDLE is correct but the selected answer one has more features. Rest VoteUP for you too....

Answer (score 1):

Based off of my comment above...

Append a drop down arrow next to the menu item for items with children - clicks on the parent item would navigate to it's link but clicks on the arrow would open up the submenu

**[JSfiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/23kfnbx7/)**

CSS:

```
ul.children {
    display: none;
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
    $('li.parent').each(function(){
        $(this).children('a').after('<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Arrow-down-navmenu.png" />');
    });

    $('li.parent img').on("click",function(){
        $(this).siblings('ul.children').toggle();
    });
});
```

EDITED JQUERY (with arrow image toggle):

```
$('li.parent img').on("click",function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
        $(this).attr('src','Arrow-down.png');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $(this).attr('src','Arrow-up.png');
    }
    $(this).siblings('ul.children').toggle();
});
```

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/23kfnbx7/3/)**

Comment: Your code is also as my desire. Can you also change ARROW images on toggle click to look more awesome...???

Comment: Yea, you would just toggle the arrow image in the click function. Check out the [**updated fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/23kfnbx7/3/) (I will also add it to the answer above).

Comment: Cool. You shared another answer but StackOverFlow have only one option to chose right. Rest VOTE UP for you... :)

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't see the full HTML, I'm acting like `main_list` is the only one.

```
// Get all anchors in menu
var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName('main_list')[0].getElementsByTagName('a');
// Change HREF to do nothing
for(a in anchors){
    a.href = "javascript:void(0);
}
// Do other stuff
```

Make that code run at the end of the page after everything has loaded. Changing the `href` to `javascript:void(0)` will make there be no action.

Comment: You can't click and have it not work, and then work without modifying your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me :)

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.main_list a').click(function (e) {
    if ($(this).parent().children('ul').is(':visible') != true) {
        $(this).parent().children('ul').show();
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
     }
   })
  });
});
```